# Enable click event into an anchor with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, anchor

I have to links (anchors) and I would like to enable and disable each one when the other is clicked.

This is one of the anchors:

```
<a href="#" id="lnkAddNew" onclick="addNewComment()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add New
</a>
```

Then I have a method that disables it like this:

```
$('#lnkAddNew').prop('onclick', null).off('click');
```

But then I want to enable the click again, but I don't want to execute the event, I just want to enable it for the use, so when I do this I not only enabling (or binding) the click event but the execution as well:

```
$('#lnkAddNew').prop('onclick', addNewComment).on('click');
```

In the last line, how can avoid executing the click event, I only want to bind the click event.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `.attr` and not `.prop` for non-boolean types.

Comment: Changed to: $('#lnkAddNew').attr('onclick', addNewComment).on('click'); but this is still triggering the event.

Comment: Don't add events using `prop('onclick')`. Add them using unobtrusive event handlers, ie. `click()` or `on('click')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to acheive here... But I made a [**demo**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qKpONo?editors=1111) of what I understand of it. You'll see that I do not use the inline `onclick` attribute at all. Tell me if that is close to the desired behavior.

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the inline onclick attribute?

Comment: Thanks guys. The demo was great Louys, this code does what I need: $(".disableToggle").on("click",disableLinks);

Comment: not sure how to mark this as solved.

Comment: I would advise that @LouysPatriceBessette repost their comment as an Answer. Then you can mark it as an answer. No way to mark a comment as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty. I did. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a method to register event handlers: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

To unregister a specific handler, the trick is to have it as a named function...
You just have to pass the function name as the second argument of [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```js
function disableLinks(){
  console.log("CLICK!");
  $(".disableToggle").off("click",disableLinks);
}

$(".disableToggle").on("click",disableLinks);

$("#restore").on("click",function(){
  $(".disableToggle").on("click",disableLinks);
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="lnkAddNew" class="disableToggle">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add New
</a><br>
<br>
<a href="#" id="lnkAddAnother" class="disableToggle">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add another
</a><br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="restore">Restore the click handler</button>
```